# Multithreaded web scraping - how to make it faster?

Tags: python

I have a list with 10 elements and this each elements will take into the url, so 10 urls should be read and get the same data. I have had help from one of experts here so I have tried multi-threading. But it still takes too long time, how can I improve and make it about 10-15 seconds?

`ticker = ['GE', 'F', 'BAC', 'CCL', 'DAL', 'OXY', 'WFC', 'BA', 'T', 'MRO']`

This list is also coming from one website.

My problem taking too much time is the code below.
Any chance I can get it quicker? I am hopeless and would really appreciate your help in advance.

```
result = []

def fetch(tick):
    url = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+tick+"?p="+tick+"&.tsrc=fin-srch-v1")
    yahoo = requests.get(url)
    access2 = BeautifulSoup(yahoo.text,'html.parser')
    rows = access2.select('#quote-summary > div > table > tbody > tr > td > span')
    result.extend(rows)


def executor():
    threads = []
    for tick in ticker:
        t = threading.Thread(target=fetch, args=(tick,))  # Create a new thread
        t.start()  # Execute the target of the thread - fetch
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()  # Wait for the child thread to complete

    return result
```

Comment: How "long" is long here? Your comment on your previous question implied it's now taking 45 seconds. If that's for all the ten URLs (not each), Depending on your internet & CPU speed, processing 10 URLs in 45 seconds may be already good enough.

Comment: @Martheen, yes mine also takes about 45 seconds, but apparently others, including my prof claim that it should be within 10 - 15 seconds and they managed their code to be within 10 - 15 sec.. I am so hopeless

Comment: When you run it, is the CPU/network interface being maxed out? Maybe try running it on a cloud VM, Google, Azure, and AWS have free trials. I really can't see further improvement, your current code seems as good as it gets unless they're using different libraries.

Comment: @Martheen, Thank you.

Comment: This is likely too broad/vague. Have you tried anything, done any research? It sounds like you need a guide or tutorial, there are plenty of resources on the subject already. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC, yeah I have been working on this for a week now. I have never used programming in my life before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gevent

Here is a good example for it: https://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_socket()

import gevent
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

def fetch(tick):
    url = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+tick+"?p="+tick+"&.tsrc=fin-srch-v1")
    yahoo = requests.get(url)
    access2 = BeautifulSoup(yahoo.text,'html.parser')
    rows = access2.select('#quote-summary > div > table > tbody > tr > td > span')
    result.extend(rows)



def asynchronous():
    threads = []
    for tick in ticker:
        threads.append(gevent.spawn(fetch, tick))
    gevent.joinall(threads)


asynchronous()
```

Comment: Sir, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplejson'..

Comment: I tried it with `import json` and no error, but still it takes just as long as before..

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, as an example.

```
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 
import pandas_datareader as dr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import seaborn as sn

start = '2019-1-1'
end = '2020-1-1'

tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','KO','JPM','MCD',    'MMM',  'MRK',  'MSFT', 'NKE','PFE','PG','TRV','UNH','RTX','VZ','V','WBA','WMT','DIS','DOW']
prices_list = []
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        prices = dr.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start)['Adj Close']
        prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
        prices.columns = [ticker]
        prices_list.append(prices)
    except:
        pass
    prices_df = pd.concat(prices_list,axis=1)
prices_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
prices_df.head()
```

[image]